# Hortonworks Sandbox on Microsoft Azure Fail

Tags: azure, hortonworks-data-platform

I stood up an instance of Hortonworks Sandbox on Microsoft Azure as documented [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hortonworks-sandbox-azure/).  After I log in, I am getting "Could not connect to localhost:10000" in Beeswax and HCat (picture attached)
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is way too late but I was having tons of problems when setting up via that link because the screen shot shows them setting up an A0 instance when in fact the base level you need is an A4 instance. See all the comments for folks getting confused and realizing that...

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSbZI.jpg) document and was able to run the instance with out any issues. 
I would recommend you to try the steps again from the tutorial and check if  you have missed anything.

From my end, I will still continue to research on why the error has taken place and write back here on any findings.

Regards,
Shirisha Paderu

Comment: Can you send the screen shot showing Hcat and Hive right after you stand up the instance?